# How to add extract text plugin for vue component css?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, components, vue-component

### I added extract text plugin for extracting sass and scss for vue component, but now I want to know how I also add extract text plugin for normal css?

[image]

Comment: Its better to post actual code here, not image since we have support for code format, here in Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

I got My answer , as like scss , sass and others ,  I just have to put css test there simply.

[image]